# Destructure and compact in javastructure

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have a variable like

```
var values = {
  foo: 'a',
  bar: 'b',
  baz: 'c'
};
```

I can destructure it and pass to another function as follow:

```
function doSomething(values) {
  var {
    foo,
    bar,
    baz
  } = values;

  passToHelper(foo, bar, baz);
};
```

But what will be shortcut to send as follow:

```
passToHelper(fooBar, baz);
```

without having to do this

```
var fooBar = {
  foo: values.foo,
  bar: values.bar
};
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `passToHelper({foo, bar}, baz)` ?

Comment: What is a “javastructure”? If `passToHelper` looks like `function passToHelper({foo, bar, baz}){`…`}`, you just need to call `passToHelper(values)`.